# Why is .index() always returning 0

Tags: jquery

I'm confused as to why .index() is returning 0 in this code.  Shouldn't it return the index of where it's found in the array of jquery objects?

```
<div id="nav">
       <ul><a href="#">Link 1</a></ul>
       <ul><a href="#">Link 2</a></ul>
       <ul><a href="#">Link 3</a></ul>
       <ul><a href="#">Link 4</a></ul>    
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="a">
        <p>this is a</p>
    </div>   
    <div class="b">
        <p>this is b</p>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
        <p>this is c</p>
    </div>
    <div class="d">
        <p>this is d</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery code

```
 $('#nav a').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).index());
    var $div = $('.parent > div').eq($(this).index());
    $div.show();
    $('.parent > div').not($div).hide();
});​
```

I have to use `$(this).index('#nav a')` to get the correct index.

http://jsfiddle.net/HpCWW/2/

Comment: Why are you nesting `a` elements in `ul`?

Comment: not my html lol.. i just copied and pasted from another post

Comment: well if you can, I'd fix the html as suggested by FishBasketGordo

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`index` is always `0` because the `<a>` is the 1st child in its parent (the `<ul>`).

Try getting the `<ul>`'s index instead.

```
$(this).parent().index()
```

NOTE: Your HTML isn't valid.  The only valid children of `<ul>`s are `<li>`s.

Comment: Ah.. so it goes index of siblings and not the returned array of objects.. Guess I misunderstood how it worked

Comment: @wirey: If you don't pass `index` a parameter, it searches within the siblings.  If you pass it a selector, it looks in that selector.  So, `$this.index('#nav a')` may also work.  (I think `$('#nav a').index(this)` would work too).  http://api.jquery.com/index/

Answer (score 7):

Another reason that `.index()` could return `0` is if you are using it like so:

```
$('matched elements').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).index()); // will be 0 in some cases
});
```

Correct way:

```
$('matched elements').click(function(){
    console.log($('matched elements').index($(this))); // will be the index within set of matched elements
});
```

Comment: not totally true - using $(element).index() gets it's index position compared to all it's siblings [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YzB2S/)

Answer (score 3):

Your anchor elements don't have any siblings, so they're all index 0. They're all nested in their own `<ul>`, which if I'm not mistaken, is invalid markup without include `<li>` around the anchors.

I would change your HTML to this:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="a">
        <p>this is a</p>
    </div>   
    <div class="b">
        <p>this is b</p>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
        <p>this is c</p>
    </div>
    <div class="d">
        <p>this is d</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And you JS to this:

```
$('.parent  div').hide();

$('#nav a').click(function() {
    // Notice, I'm going up to the parent <li> and then calling index().
    var $div = $('.parent > div').eq($(this).parent().index());
    $div.show();
    $('.parent > div').not($div).hide();
});​
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/B6zFR/)

Comment: I was typing up the same answer.. one minor change though. Change the selector to `$('#nav li')` and then you don't need `parent()`.

Comment: That would also work, but you may not want to attach the click event to the `<li>` in some cases.