# How to get index number of dynamically added elements on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the below snippet. Why am I always getting index number of `0` on clicking on each of dynamically added button?

I tried both `$(this).index()` and `'#uploadPreview').find('.card').index()` but getting same index number on each click.

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-warning", function() {
   console.log($(this).index());
   console.log($('#uploadPreview').find('.card').index());
});
```

```js
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  $('#uploadPreview').append('<div class="card"><button class="btn btn-warning">&times; - '+ i+'   </button></div><br>');
}
$(document).on("click", ".btn-warning", function() {
   console.log($(this).index());
   console.log($('#uploadPreview').find('.card').index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="uploadPreview"></div>
```

Comment: *If no argument is passed to the `.index()` method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.* - Your buttons are always the first of the sibling elements (elements within each `<div class="card">`) and therefore the index is always `0`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is .index() always returning 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783612/why-is-index-always-returning-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$(this)` is a jQuery collection with only a single element. If you want to check which index a `.btn-warning` is in the collection of `.btn-warnings`s, you need to create a collection of all `.btn-warning`s first, then pass the element you want to test into `.index`. Same sort of thing for `.card` - you need a collection of `.card`s to test an element against to find that element's index in that collection:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  $('#uploadPreview').append('<div class="card"><button class="btn btn-warning">&times; - '+ i+'   </button></div><br>');
}
$(document).on("click", ".btn-warning", function() {
  const btnWarnings = $('.btn-warning');
   console.log(btnWarnings.index(this));
   const cards = $('.card');
   console.log(cards.index(this.parentElement));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="uploadPreview"></div>
```

(also, try to avoid implicitly creating global variables - it's not only a bad idea, it'll also throw an error in strict mode. Use `let i` in the `for` loop)